# Better or recommended way to create a product page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Currently, I'm building a simple e-commerce website using node, express, and ejs. I'm done creating the product catalog which will display all or categorized product with image.

Now my concern is, which is a better way in creating the product page? Like when a user clicked the image, it will redirect onto the product page of that specific item.

I have two options in mind:

Option A: Create a separate page for each of the product. (I know this is not rational as it will be tedious and the items may grow over-time.

Option B: Create a base page, where there will be elements that are waiting for data, and that data will depend on what item the user will click.

Or if there is an option c, I will be glad to add it into my knowledge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think option B will be worked out for your execution and generally more reputation websites are used same technique that what you preferred here !